# Identity Server Not returning the Correct Access Token

Tags: identityserver3, identityserver4

I am makeing a call to identity server from angular2(java script client app), but its not returning the correct access_token, instead its returning something like

b8fee3ff98859c83e69b68376b413a542217cb9f054fc9638e885fe18650f880

Comment: It seems your client is requesting Reference access token

Comment: As MJK says, that looks like a Reference token. An `Access Token` comes in two flavours: a self-contained JWT or a Reference token. From the client viewpoint you use them both in the same way, but how they are handled behind the scenes is different. On advantage of Reference tokens is that they can be revoked, whereas a JWT is valid until it naturally expires.

Comment: Yes I was accessing the reference token, now I have removed the AccessTokenType, so now it returns the access_token.

Answer (score 1):

Like the comments suggest, your client is returning reference tokens. If you want your client to get self contained access tokens make sure your client is of the form:

```
var angular_client = new Client 
{
    ClientId = "angular_client",
    AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt, //You probably have this set to .Reference
    AccessTokenLifeTime = 3600,
    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
    ... 
}
```